# Remap square bracket commands to fit a swiss layout keyboard

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode, keyboard-layout

I'm new to vim and currently trying to understand the different commands. `:help index` shows me a list of all commands for each mode. Section 2.3 is about "Square bracket commands" like `[*` and `]*`.

I'm using a [Swiss German keyboard](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/KB_Swiss.svg/800px-KB_Swiss.svg.png). The positions for <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> are more ore less the same as they are on a [US keyboard](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg/800px-KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg.png) but on a Swiss keyboard I have to keep <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> pressed to reach the brackets. By just pressing the keys (without <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>) I get `ü` (instead of `[`) and `¨` instead of `]`.

Is it possible to map all square bracket commands like so?

- `[*` to `ü*` and
- `]*` to `¨*`

I think that would be more comfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add to your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap ü [
nnoremap ¨ ]
...
```

Comment: When I type the `¨` while writing this comment, it behaves as a dead key. But on my gnome-terminal it doesn't; it prints it immediately. So I assume it would work (I have to try). But I was hoping there is a way to tell VIM to treat "ü" generally as "[" for all cases (just in normal mode of course) instead of having to remap everything. Sure, it's a finite set anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
Actually I didn't use any of the square bracket commands so far. But I did now two tests:
`nnoremap ¨D ]D` and `nnoremap üf [f` and it worked. I verified it by the error message that is shown after sending this commands. They was the same error messages. Btw. I'm using the Swiss German layout. Can you confirm, that it isn't possible to map them all with one line per bracket ([ ])?

Comment: I confirm that you need one line per mapping there are no ways to have wildcard in mapping. If the solution fit don't forget to validate it using the v button next to the arrow voting button. It help the question rest. I'll be glad to update it to the correct layout (maybe could you add that your are using the German Swiss layout in the question).

Comment: Btw. I could not find what `[q` and `]q` are, which you did remap. They are not listed in section 2.3 of `:help index`.

Comment: I'm using a very common [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin from Tim Pope that add some additional bracket mapping (`]q` go to the next quick fix error, ...)

Comment: I just tried `nmap ü [` and `nmap ¨ ]`. This does allow recursive mapping, so that by pressing `ü` or `¨` it will be interpreted as `[` respectively as `]`. That way I can map all possible cases. Do you see any problem with this? If not, could you update your answer or maybe comment this why this wouldn't be a good idea? Thanks again.

Comment: You are fully right :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142911/discussion-between-vivian-de-smedt-and-arber).